# How to remove small object in image with Python

Tags: python, image, numpy, image-processing, computer-vision

i have a problem with my python code. I want to make image processing with chest X-rays in order to obtain a lung pattern. but my code results still have little stains. how to get rid of these small objects

[image]

and this is my code

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from skimage import morphology

im = cv2.imread('image.jpg')
ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(im, 150, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
kernel = np.ones((5, 5), np.uint8)
opening = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel)
cleaned = morphology.remove_small_objects(opening, min_size=62, connectivity=2)
cv2.imshow("cleaned", cleaned)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

P.S :
when i try with the matlab code, the small object can be removed with this code

```
K=bwareaopen(~K,1500); %Remove small object (area) pixels less than 1500 pixels
```

and that code can remove small object well:

[image]

Answer (score 14):

You can filter using contour area then apply morpholgical closing to fill the small holes in the image. Here's the result:

[image]

```
import cv2

# Load image, convert to grayscale, Gaussian blur, Otsu's threshold
image = cv2.imread('1.jpg')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (3,3), 0)
thresh = cv2.threshold(blur, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

# Filter using contour area and remove small noise
cnts = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
for c in cnts:
    area = cv2.contourArea(c)
    if area < 5500:
        cv2.drawContours(thresh, [c], -1, (0,0,0), -1)

# Morph close and invert image
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (5,5))
close = 255 - cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel, iterations=2)

cv2.imshow('thresh', thresh)
cv2.imshow('close', close)
cv2.waitKey()
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [Documentation for bwareaopen](https://in.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/bwareaopen.html) you can find the algorithm that is used in the method, which is:

> Determine the connected components:
>
> CC = bwconncomp(BW, conn);
>
> Compute the area of each component:
>
> S = regionprops(CC, 'Area');
>
> Remove small objects:
>
> L = labelmatrix(CC);
>
> BW2 = ismember(L, find([S.Area] >= P));

You could simply follow these steps to get to the result.

Comment: This is not my idea. Matlad provides an algorithm or a pseudo code for almost all their image processing API. I simply copy pasted from the link specified in the answer.