# How do I filter by area or eccentricity using skimage.measure.regionprops on a binary image in Python

Tags: python, image-processing, image-segmentation, scikit-image

I have a binary image of a road surface and I am trying to isolate the pothole only. Using skimage.measure.regionprops and skimage.measure.label I can produce a table of properties for different labels within the image.

How do I then filter using those values? - for instance using area or axis length or eccentricity to turn off certain labels.
[Input, labled Image and properties table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cObZt.png)

using python 3

Comment: I'm confused. Are you asking how to determine which component has the largest `area` in your table?

Comment: I am asking how to remove the smaller objects from the image. very similar to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60033274/how-to-remove-small-object-in-image-with-python

However I cannot get this to work. I was wondering if there was a way using skimage.measure

Comment: If you've already got your image labeled, why not just create a new image with only the largest object?

Comment: That is exactly what I want to do, although I would like to filter by eccentricity rather than area. How do I remove labelled parts? - or create a new image with just certain labels?
sorry for my ineptitude, am quite new to this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use pandas together with [`skimage.measure.regionprops_table`](https://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/api/skimage.measure.html#regionprops-table) to get what you want:

```py
import pandas as pd
import imageio as iio
from skimage.measure import regionprops_table, label

image = np.asarray(iio.imread('path/to/image.png'))
labeled = label(image > 0)  # ensure input is binary
data = regionprops_table(
        labeled,
        properties=('label', 'eccentricity'),
        )
table = pd.DataFrame(data)
table_sorted_by_ecc = table.sort_values(
        by='eccentricity', ascending=False
        )

# print e.g. the 10 most eccentric labels
print(table_sorted.iloc[:10])
```

If you then want to e.g. produce the label image with *only* the most eccentric label, you can do:

```py
eccentric_label = table['labels'].iloc[np.argmax(table['eccentricity'])]
labeled_ecc = np.where(labeled == eccentric_label, eccentric_label, 0)
```

You can also do more sophisticated things, e.g. make a label image with only labels above a certain eccentricity. Below, we use NumPy elementwise multiplication to produce an array that is the original label if that label has high eccentricity, or 0 otherwise. We then use the [`skimage.util.map_array`](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.util.html#skimage.util.map_array) function to map the original labels to either themselves or 0, again, depending on the eccentricity.

```py
from skimage.util import map_array

ecc_threshold = 0.3
eccentric_labels = table['labels'] * (table['eccentricity'] > ecc_threshold)
new_labels = map_array(
        labeled,
        np.asarray(table['labels']),
        np.asarray(eccentric_labels),
        )
```

Comment: Thanks, this is really helpful!